# Why is samba unable to access a folder once something is mounted to it?

Tags: samba

**Edit**: IT WAS F#$CKING SELINUX. `echo 0 >/selinux/enforce` and it works.

**Edit**: Based on the fact I can't view files in the directory even when they are recursively set to ugo+rwx (see edits at bottom of this post), I suspect the problem is more fundamental than the mounted share.

I have the following share setup in my samba configuration:

```
[test]
path = /mnt/
guest ok = yes
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
```

The /mnt folder has permissions as follows:

```
[root@[host-redacted] mnt]# ls -al /mnt
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Mar  3 00:54 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root root 4096 Feb 25 19:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Feb 26 21:45 files
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Mar  3 00:54 tmp
```

At this point, nothing is mounted to these folders. When I try to access this via samba it works fine:

```
[root@[host-redacted] mnt]# smbclient -Uguest //[host-redacted]/test
Enter guest's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-125.el6]
smb: \> ls
  .                                   D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013
  ..                                 DR        0  Mon Feb 25 19:04:02 2013
  tmp                                 D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013
  files                               D        0  Tue Feb 26 21:45:55 2013

                50396 blocks of size 1048576. 46487 blocks available
smb: \> cd files
smb: \files\> ls
  .                                   D        0  Tue Feb 26 21:45:55 2013
  ..                                  D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013

                50396 blocks of size 1048576. 46487 blocks available
```

However after I mount an encrypted share to that drive things to awry. I mount it and check permissions and ownership are identical:

```
[root@[host-redacted] mnt]# mount /dev/mapper/[encrypted-partition-redacted] files

[root@[host-redacted] mnt]# ls -al /mnt/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Mar  3 00:54 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root root 4096 Feb 25 19:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 4096 Jul  6  2012 files
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Mar  3 00:54 tmp
```

But now when I access the share, the files directory has disappeared:

```
[root@[host-redacted] ~]# smbclient -Uguest //[host-redacted]/test
Enter guest's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-125.el6]
smb: \> ls
  .                                   D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013
  ..                                 DR        0  Mon Feb 25 19:04:02 2013
  tmp                                 D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013

                50396 blocks of size 1048576. 46487 blocks available
```

I did a quick check to make sure my guest user (nobody) can read /mnt and it seems okay:

```
[root@[host-redacted] mnt]# sudo -u nobody ls /mnt
files  tmp
```

Can someone explain what is going on? My samba configuration was copied from a previous machine running samba 3.3 in much the same setup, and this new setup is running the same configuration (files copied) but with samba `3.5.10-125.el6`.

I've also checked the [changelog](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_3.5_Features_added/changed#Major_enhancements_in_Samba_3.5.0_include:) and can't see anything that stands out.

**edit:** I do not have any veto files directive in my smb.conf:

```
[root@pmfs mnt]# grep -i veto /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

**edit2**: When the directory is not mounted I am able to cd into files - *HOWEVER* I am not able to see a file I created there

```
[root@pmfs samba]# echo asdf > /mnt/files/test.txt

[root@pmfs files]# chmod -R ugo+rwx /mnt/files/

[root@pmfs ~]# smbclient -Uguest //pmfs/test
Enter guest's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-125.el6]
smb: \> ls
  .                                   D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013
  ..                                 DR        0  Mon Feb 25 19:04:02 2013
  tmp                                 D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013
  files                               D        0  Mon Mar  4 20:05:45 2013

                50396 blocks of size 1048576. 46486 blocks available
smb: \> cd files
smb: \files\> ls
  .                                   D        0  Mon Mar  4 20:05:45 2013
  ..                                  D        0  Sun Mar  3 00:54:52 2013

                50396 blocks of size 1048576. 46486 blocks available
```

*As well as a solution to this specific problem I'd be interested in knowing if there is anything else I should be doing to troubleshoot this problem - as I have often struggled with configuring samba I'm always interested in learning how to better improve the troubleshooting process*

Comment: Do you have "veto files" entries in your config? Can you cd into files via smbclient?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - answered your questions at bottom of post. TLDR: No veto files; I can cd into files, but can't access contents there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> IT WAS F#$CKING SELINUX. echo 0 >/selinux/enforce and it works.

Rather than just disabling SELinux for everything (echo 0 >/selinux/enforce) just configure SElinux to allow samba access

```
 chcon -R -t samba_share_t /mnt/files
```

which will give samba access. You can then use

```
 semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/mnt/files"
```

to ensure that a subsequent restorecon doesn't unfix this.